# Batch prediction using a trained Object Detection APIs model and TF 2

Tags: tensorflow, object, batch-processing, prediction, detection

I successfully trained a model using Object Detection APIs for TF 2 on TPUs which is saved as a .pb (SavedModel format). I then load it back using `tf.saved_model.load` and it works fine when predicting boxes using a single image converted to a tensor with shape `(1, w, h, 3)`.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

# Load Object Detection APIs model
detect_fn = tf.saved_model.load('/path/to/saved_model/')

image = tf.io.read_file(image_path)
image_np = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image, channels=3).numpy()
input_tensor = np.expand_dims(image_np, 0)
detections = detect_fn(input_tensor) # This works fine
```

Problem is I need to make this a batch prediction to scale it to half a million images, but the input signature of this model seems to be limited to handling only data with shape `(1, w, h, 3)`.
This also means that I can't use batch processing with Tensorflow Serving.
How can I solve this problem? Can I merely change the model Signature to handle batches of data?

All work (loading model + predictions) was performed inside the official container released with the Object Detection APIs (from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection/dockerfiles/tf2))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have met this issue recently. When you use `exporter_main_v2.py` to convert checkpoint files to `.pb` file, it will call `exporter_lib_v2.py`. I figured that in file `exporter_lib_v2.py` ([here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/51e2004cdf6ee1f2db8848b9898fd5a67f145782/research/object_detection/exporter_lib_v2.py#L138)), TF2 hard fixed the input signature with shape `[1, None, None, 3]`. We have to change it to `[None, None, None, 3]`

Need to modify those lines in that file ([138](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/51e2004cdf6ee1f2db8848b9898fd5a67f145782/research/object_detection/exporter_lib_v2.py#L138), [162](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/51e2004cdf6ee1f2db8848b9898fd5a67f145782/research/object_detection/exporter_lib_v2.py#L162), [170](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/51e2004cdf6ee1f2db8848b9898fd5a67f145782/research/object_detection/exporter_lib_v2.py#L170), [185](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/51e2004cdf6ee1f2db8848b9898fd5a67f145782/research/object_detection/exporter_lib_v2.py#L185)) from `1` to `None`. Then rebuild the TF2 Object Detector API Repo ([link](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#install-the-object-detection-api)) and use new built version to export `.pb` again.